# Drop Down Menu and separate Unordered list

Tags: html, css

here is my code:

http://cssdesk.com/9cWbV

I wanted to "add products etc." like a vertical list but it conflicts on my navigation bar any tips? on which should i change because I'm confused as hell and I need help in drop down for nagivation bar too

Comment: Can you be more specific? Not getting what you are looking for :/

Comment: Please explain yourself better.

Comment: drop down code for navigation bar

and horizontal unordered list for add products and etc. view the code on css desk i refered above

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I'm understanding you. 
but if you want to have a dropdown menu in the nav bar maybe you should add class="dropdown-menu" to the ul

```
    .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
      box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

for more css check bootstrap documentation.
also I recommand to use the whole bootstrap for your frontend

Comment: do you have skype,ym can we talk there at least I'm slow and didn't get any of this :(